# Which Strategy is Better To Use When Working With Push Notification In terms of performance And Efficiency?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, push-notification

Now that i have discovered the push technique in primefaces, I am wondering which of these two ways are better to use in terms of performance.

I am Creating a Dashboard in java with spring and primefaces.

Right now i have one channel for all dashlets, I am broadcasting a message alongside a uuid to all pages and each page is responsible to check if the the given uuid concerns it or not. If the answer is yes the page will do the desired action, like showing the message or just refreshing itself.

For example in almighty java :

```
pushContext.push("/refresh-chan", getUuid().toString());
```

and in XHTML side:

```
<p:socket  onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/refresh-chan" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(uuid) {
        var myUuid = '#{myBean.id}';
        //console.log(myUuid + "-"+uuid);
        if(uuid==myUuid)
        {
            //console.log("- I am refreshing myself : my id="+uuid);
            location.reload();
        }
    }
</script>
```

But there is an other way to handle this in which i can create a separate channel for each dashlet and push the context for that dashlet alone:

Notice : The code is imaginary and it may not function:

```
pushContext.push("/refresh-chan"+getUuid().toString(),"may leave empty");
```

and in XHTML page (Yup! still imaginary) :

```
<p:socket  onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/refresh-chan"+#{myBean.id} />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(dummy) {
            location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

In addition to performance and efficiency consider that the code is part of a framework that i am building and other developers will have to write their own XHTML pages and then add the XHTML part of the code(demonstrated above) in their pages too, so it should be easy for them  to understand what is happening .

thank you